# PHP + HTML Resultado inesperado com $_GET

Tags: php, html, netbeans, get

Não está recebendo o valor false, e exibindo o bloco do else. Foi passado pela url e só executa o bloco do if de valor true. Alguém me da um help, desde já agradeço. Segue o código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<?php $logado = $_GET["logado"]; ?>

<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>IF Alternativo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if($logado) : ?>

    </body>
</html>      <h1>Bem vindo ao sistema!</h1>


        <?php else : ?>

        <h1>Faça o login</h1>

        <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Login" name="login"/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
        </form>

            <?php endif; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: O logado é uma string, você já tentou comparar $logado === "true" ? Ou como ele está passando na url, valor 1/0/true/false?

Comment: Sem ser por $_GET, passando true ou false, diretamente para a variável $logado, da certo, só que quero obter por $_GET["logado"] esse valor.

Comment: Ok, tente colocar assim `$logado = (boolean) $_GET['logado'];`

Comment: Adicionei o (boolean) e não deu certo. Tem alguma outra forma para resolver ? Usando $_GET

Comment: tanto "true" quanto "false" são verdadeiros quando se trata de string. Tente da forma que o @RafaelWithoeft recomendou: `if ($logado === 'true') ` para fazer uma comparação literal. Notar que maiúsculas e minúsculas fazem diferença neste caso.

Comment: @Thiago, qual o valor que está vindo na variável $logado ? ou melhor na url? Qual o valor passado na url?

Comment: O valor é false, só que exibe o conteúdo do if. Sendo que era pra entrar no else.

Comment: Você testou if($logado === 'true') ?

Comment: @Thiago Você não pode colar a URL aqui pra gente ver?

Comment: Testei aqui agora, resolveu, Muito obrigado @RafaelWithoeft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta alterar para isso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<?php $logado = $_GET["logado"]; ?>

<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>IF Alternativo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if($logado == 'true') { ?>

            <h1>Bem vindo ao sistema!</h1>

        <?php } else { ?>

            <h1>Faça o login</h1>

            <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Login" name="login"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha"/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
            </form>

        <?php } ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

[**Edição**]
A sintaxe usando `:` é suportada pelo `php`, falha minha.
*Você está usando `:` e não `{` e `}` para definir o bloco delimitado pelo `if`.*

Outra coisa também é que seu `html` está sendo fechado antes da tag `h1` como pode ver abaixo:

> ```
> </body> </html>      <h1>Bem vindo ao sistema!</h1>
>
>     <?php else : ?>
> ```

Uma outra coisa que você também deve considerar é armazenar o valor da variável $logado em uma sessão e não passá-la usando o método `GET`, mesmo que seja só para exibição da mensagem de bem vindo / login para o usuário. Além disso a URL da aplicação fica mais limpa.

Comment: A sintaxe if: é aceita. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.if.php#112231

Comment: Obrigado @RafaelWithoeft , não sabia deste detalhe, sempre usei as chaves, e nunca havia visto esta sintaxe. Já atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Sempre estamos aprendendo alguma coisa, afinal ninguém sabe tudo :)

Comment: Richard, valeu por responder, executei o código alterado e continua não exibindo o bloco depois do else. Com você o valor false passado pela url apresentou a tela de login ?

Comment: @Thiago, alterei a condição do `if`, acredito que agora irá resolver.

Comment: @RichardDias Alterei aqui e resolveu, muito obrigado.